# IPA Tastes Sweet - Undercarbed?

Tags: carbonation

I brewed a NEIPA, fermented in the primary for 10 days and straight into bottles that I left condition for 2 weeks.

The OG was 1.067 and FG is 1.016

Here's the full recipe - https://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/view/671365/neipa-v3

The beer after 2 weeks bottle conditioning tastes pretty sweet and doesn't seem to be fully carbed. Would the sweetness just be down to the carb drops having not been fully consumed by the yeast yet? I'm thinking the beer fermented out fully and I don't remember noting that the samples were that sweet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two weeks can be a bit short sometimes for carbonation.  Be sure the bottles are being stored in a room temperature spot. Keep them off the floor, or insulate the box from the ground somehow if that's the case.

Take a couple bottles and put them some place warmer than that.  On top of your fridge or nearer to a heat source/vent. Give it another 7-10 days, chill and then crack open one of these test bottles.  If its carbed up then all things are going fine it will just take some time for the other bottles to catch up.

Comment: Cool, yeah the weather got a good bit colder after I bottled. Luckily there's a mini heat wave for the next week so that should hopefully get them back on track. There's way too much hops in the beer to be that overpowered by that much sweetness and I don't think it's coming from the malt.